# What are all the ways to kill people?

Tags: the-darkness-2

I've been enjoying a bloodbath playing The Darkness II, and I was wondering how to get creative.

As of now, I know you can get Darkling Kills (by using your Darkling against enemies), you can impale people, slice them, kill them with your Darkness Arms, and of course, guns... lots of guns.

What are all the ways you can kill people, and how many Darkness Points are given by each?

Comment: Throwing a car door at someone's head and watching it explode is always enjoyable :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is all of them.

### Weapons

- **Kill** (+10)
- **Headshot** (+20)
- **Signature weapon kill** (+20) - in Vendetta mode, each playable character has a unique signature weapon
- **Execution** (+30) - in Vendetta mode, players can execute staggered enemies with their signature weapon, which also provides a health bonus and invincibility (when upgraded)

### Thrown objects

- **Lethal** (+20) - any lethal thrown object that has its own bonus (like *Impaled* for cues, or *Sliced* for car doors) qualifies for this
- **Kill** (+10) - if you bludgeon a hurt enemy with an object that would normally just stun them (like a chair), it'll be a boring old kill

### Darkness powers

- **Demon Arm Kill** (+20)
- **Swarm Kill** (+25)
- **Gun Channeling Kill** (+25)
- **Ground Pound** (+25) - slashing an enemy into the air and then into the ground, after you've unlocked it.
- **Demon Arm Throw** (+10) - when you kill a grabbed enemy by throwing them
- **Kill** (+10) - if you grab an enemy and don't do anything with him, the Demon Arms will get bored and kill him on their own
- **Execution** (+30) - when you grab staggered enemies, you can perform different executions for different benefits, such as health, ammo, or a shield, but they're always worth the same amount of Essence